# Cannot open files from within a plperlu function

Tags: perl, postgresql, io

I'm trying to write to a file from within a plperlu function and I'm getting Permission Denied errors.

```
ERROR:  error from Perl function "[$name]": could not open the file: Permission denied at line 46.
```

I can write to a file using a perl script that essentially does the same thing. I have read-write permissions and I've also configured the pg_hba.conf file correctly. And idea what might be causing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have the necessary permissions but the PostgreSQL server probably isn't running as you. Your plperlu code will be running in the server's context with the server's permissions. A quick and easy way to check would be to change the file path to something in `/tmp` and see if it works; if it does then you just need to write your file somewhere that the PostgreSQL server has write access to.

Comment: You Sir, are a genius! Silly of me to forget about that :)